# CSS – Blurring image with un-blurred text

Tags: css

I have `div` elements that are 200px tall and 200px wide, and I am filling each `div` element with an image of a person.

Upon hovering on the image, I want the image to be blurred, but I simultaneously want text to appear on the image (unblurred) that gives a description of who they are. Does anyone know how to do this?

So far, this is what I am getting: 
[image]

Here is the CSS code:

```
.mem1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px 31px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
  background-image: url(members/giles.png);
}

.mem1 p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 70px 30px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mem1:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

.mem1:hover p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 70px 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: @Anonymous CSS absolutely can do that. Check out the filter blur property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: try this site: http://designshack.net/articles/css/joshuajohnson-2/

Comment: We'd need to see your markup, but, in general, you'd want to make sure the text isn't a child of the object you are blurring. My guess is you have a div with a background image and child text. If you blur that div, the child text will also be blurred.

Comment: @DA. I uploaded my code, and yes that's what I did

Comment: @faze2 then that's the problem. Move the text out of the DIV. Or, alternatively, put it in a sibling div. There's a number ways to handle it. Again, though, we need to see the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the text is a child of the element that you are blurring. You can't do that. You need to do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blurredPhoto"></div>
    <div class="text">Your Text</div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
} 

.blurredPhoto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Then apply your blurring logic only to the .blurredPhoto object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that does what you are looking for - blurring an image when you mouse over it, while simultaneously showing a textual description.

The key is that you need to use the `:hover` pseudoclass on the div, then when the div is hovered, you blur the image only, and show the description text span.

```css
.blur {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

.blur img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.blur span {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}
 
.blur:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.blur span {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}

.blur:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur pic">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97350&w=350&h=350">
  <span>This is a photo of something.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DA explained you need to get a parent container involved. Here's a working fiddle using your example code: https://jsfiddle.net/m25gkqkL/1/

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="mem1"></div>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>

.mem1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px 31px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;

  background-image: url(members/giles.png);
  z-index: 1;/* added */
  position: relative;/* added */
}

.parent {/* added this */
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 262px;
}

.parent p {/* modified */
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 50%;/* modified */
  margin-top: -0.5em;/* added */
  width: 262px;/* added */
  z-index: 2;/* added */
}

.parent:hover .mem1 {/* modified */
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

.parent:hover p {/* modified */
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I'll try to find a 200px x 200px image to stick in there to better illustrate but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
    position: relative;
}

.text-child{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}

.text-child h1{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;   
}

.parent:hover img{
    filter: blur(4px);
}

.parent:hover .text-child{
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="text-child">
        <h1> hi this is text.<h1>
    </div>
    <img src="/images/excel.png" alt="">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what did you change ?